R Create a pivot table that calculates percentages of multiple groups
This is my sample data set
sample <- structure(list(Week  = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                         Project = c("A", "A", "A",  "A",  "B",  "B",  "B",  "B",  "C",  "C",  "C",  "A", "A",   "A" ), 
                    Status= c( "Active","Rescheduled","Active", "Cancelled", "Active", "Cancelled",  "Cancelled", 
                               "Rescheduled",  "Active",  "Active",   "Rescheduled", "Cancelled", "Cancelled", "Active")),
                    .Names = c("Week","Project","Status"),
                      class = "data.frame" , row.names = c(NA, -14L))

> sample
   Week Project      Status
1     1       A      Active
2     1       A Rescheduled
3     1       A      Active
4     1       A   Cancelled
5     1       B      Active
6     1       B   Cancelled
7     1       B   Cancelled
8     1       B Rescheduled
9     2       C      Active
10    2       C      Active
11    2       C Rescheduled
12    2       A   Cancelled
13    2       A   Cancelled
14    2       A      Active

and I want to create a data frame calculates each Program's actve rate and 1-active rate(=Non active rate) by Week, with 'NA' values
So the table would look like this
  Week A_active_rate A_Non_active_rate B_active_rate B_Non_active_rate C_active_rate C_Non_active_rate
1    1          0.50              0.50          0.25              0.75            NA                NA
2    2          0.33              0.67            NA                NA          0.67              0.33


Another tidyverse approach:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

sample %>%
  summarize(
    active_rate = mean(Status == "Active"),
    Non_active_rate = 1 - active_rate,
    .by = c(Week, Project)
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Project,
    values_from = active_rate:Non_active_rate,
    names_glue = "{Project}_{.value}",
    names_vary = "slowest"
  )
# # A tibble: 2 × 7
#    Week A_active_rate A_Non_active_rate B_active_rate B_Non_active_rate C_active_rate C_Non_active_rate
#   <dbl>         <dbl>             <dbl>         <dbl>             <dbl>         <dbl>             <dbl>
# 1     1         0.5               0.5            0.25              0.75        NA                NA    
# 2     2         0.333             0.667         NA                NA            0.667             0.333


I ran 'rlang' library but still getting an error: Error in chr_as_locations():
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column Project doesn't exist.
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.

What does rlang have to do with anything? This code runs fine for me with your example data - could you edit your post to include data that produces the error? Since the error is saying the column Project doesn't exist, have you confirmed that column exists in your data?

Here's one approach:
library(tidyverse)

sample <- structure(list(Week  = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                         Project = c("A", "A", "A",  "A",  "B",  "B",  "B",  "B",  "C",  "C",  "C",  "A", "A",   "A" ), 
                         Status= c( "Active","Rescheduled","Active", "Cancelled", "Active", "Cancelled",  "Cancelled", 
                                    "Rescheduled",  "Active",  "Active",   "Rescheduled", "Cancelled", "Cancelled", "Active")),
                    .Names = c("Week","Project","Status"),
                    class = "data.frame" , row.names = c(NA, -14L))

sample %>%
  mutate(active_or_not = ifelse(Status == "Active", "Active", "Non_Active")) %>%
  mutate(count = n(), .by = c(Week, Project, active_or_not)) %>%
  mutate(perc = count / n(), .by = c(Week, Project)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(Project, active_or_not),
              id_cols = Week,
              values_from = perc,
              values_fn = mean,
              values_fill = NA,
              names_glue = "{.name}_rate")
#> # A tibble: 2 × 7
#>    Week A_Active_rate A_Non_Active_rate B_Active_rate B_Non_Active_rate
#>   <dbl>         <dbl>             <dbl>         <dbl>             <dbl>
#> 1     1         0.5               0.5            0.25              0.75
#> 2     2         0.333             0.667         NA                NA   
#> # ℹ 2 more variables: C_Active_rate <dbl>, C_Non_Active_rate <dbl>

Created on 2024-04-11 with reprex v2.1.0

Why am I getting this error? Thank you;

sample %>%


dplyr::summarise(

active_rate = mean(Status == "Active"),



Non_active_rate = 1 - active_rate,



.by = c(Week, Project)


) %>%
tidyr::pivot_wider(

names_from = Project,



values_from = active_rate:Non_active_rate,



names_glue = "{Project}_{.value}",



names_vary = "slowest"


)
Error in chr_as_locations():
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column Project doesn't exist.
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.

